# Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL while Indexing in SOLR

Tags: solr

I am stuck while doing through example- "Testing Index Sharding on Two Local Servers" from following URL: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding

Now, for indexing I am giving following command - 
`D:\K\solr-6.3.0\bin>java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/#/core
1/update -jar D:\K\solr-6.3.0\example\exampledocs\post.jar D:\K\solr-6.3.0\examp
le\exampledocs\monitor.xml`

& I am getting following error-

```
D:\K\solr-6.3.0\bin>java -Dtype=text/csv -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/#/core
1/update -jar D:\K\solr-6.3.0\example\exampledocs\post.jar D:\K\solr-6.3.0\examp
le\exampledocs\monitor.xml
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/#/core1/update using cont
ent-type text/csv...
POSTing file monitor.xml to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #405 (HTTP method POST is not su
pported by this URL) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/core1/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/index.html. Reason:
<pre>    HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException
: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/
core1/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/#/core1/update...
Time spent: 0:00:00.117
```

Kindly Help !!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command :

```
D:\K\solr-6.3.0\bin\post -c collection_name D:\K\solr-6.3.0\examp
le\exampledocs\monitor.xml
```

Replace collection_name with your collection name

Comment: `D:\K\solr-6.3.0\bin>post -c core1 D:\K\solr-6.3.0\exampledocs\monitor.xml
'post' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I use linux i have  these file in solr home init.d  install_solr_service.sh  oom_solr.sh  post  solr  solr-8983.pid  solr.cmd  solr.in.cmd  solr.in.sh

Comment: I use windows, post.jar was not there in my solr home, but before when i ran the above said command, I copied it in my home location. Still it gave the above error. That was the reason to give the full path for post.jar earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The url you are putting contains the # ( anchor tag ) which will not be traversed using normal connection. Just remove it and try the url as

http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/update